# (Repl.it) Python 3 Email Not Working?

Tags: python, email

```
import smtplib

email_user = 'myemail'

email_send = 'myemail'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

server.starttls()

server.login( email_user, "PASSWORD")

msg = "Hello"

server.sendmail(email_user,email_send, msg)

server.quit()
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "python", line 7, in socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I am using Repl.it; is this the reason for it not working?

Comment: _when i type the code it says there is an error_ You're making us guess what the error is.  Please edit your question to include the full error message.

Comment: @JohnGordon I have made an edit, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
import smtplib 
import email
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.Utils import COMMASPACE
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.parser import Parser
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEAudio import MIMEAudio
import mimetypes

def send(user, password, fromaddr, to, subject, body):
smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
smtp_port = 587
server = smtplib.SMTP()
server.connect(smtp_host,smtp_port)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(user, password)

msg = email.MIMEMultipart.MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = email.Utils.COMMASPACE.join(to)
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg.attach(MIMEText(body))
server.sendmail(user,to,msg.as_string())
```

Comment: Doesnt Work, I keep getting error messages. Is this because im  using repl.it?

Comment: You will use python2.